# How does free living nitrogen fixing bacteria fix N2 in aerobic condition?

Tags: nitrogen-cycle

If a *Azotobacter* is free living nitrogen fixer it will also require ATP through cellular respiration. I am confused here: if Nitrogenase is highly sensitive to oxygen molecule how will *Azotobacter* be able to fix N2 and carry out cellular respiration at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azotobacter#Nitrogen_fixation

> Nitrogen fixation is highly sensitive to the presence of oxygen, so
> Azotobacter developed a special defensive mechanism against oxygen,
> namely a significant intensification of metabolism that reduces the
> concentration of oxygen in the cells.[40]

From that cite ["Respiratory Protection nitrogenase complex in Azotobacter vinelandii"](https://web.archive.org/web/20110722134518/http://www.inbi.ras.ru/ubkh/45/bertsova.pdf)(google translated)

> The second strategy, dubbed "breath protection ", is based on a
> significant increase in the rate of the rate of respiration, resulting
> in the concentration of oxygen in the cytoplasm decreases to a level at
> which nitrogenase no longer experiences damaging action О2 .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azotobacter#Nitrogen_fixation

> Also, a special nitrogenase-protective protein protects nitrogenase
> and is involved in protecting the cells from oxygen. Mutants not
> producing this protein are killed by oxygen during nitrogen fixation
> in the absence of a nitrogen source in the medium.[41]